# After logged in with Gmail Webpage Opened in new tab

Tags: javascript, php, facebook, popup, gmail

I had implemented authentication to my webpage using gmail, fb and twitter. When I logged in with gmail in a popup, it's redirecting to the same popup and my webpage got opened in the popup only.

I had used `header("Location:/index.php/");` after insert query but still it is opening in new tab after logged in with Gmail or Facebook. Also tried with `window.return and $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERAL']` in header.

Do I need to change anything in pop up?

```
<SCRIPT TYPE="text/javascript">
function popup(mylink, windowname){

if (! window.focus) {
   return true;
}

var href;

if (typeof(mylink) == 'string'){
   href=mylink;
} else {
   href=mylink.href;
}

window.open(href, windowname, 'width=400,height=200,scrollbars=yes');
return false;

}
</SCRIPT>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tried your code and found that window.open function goes to the url in the new tab. However for same tab one need to add "_self" parameter to windown.open function.

For example,

```
window.open(href, windowname, 'width=400,height=200,scrollbars=yes');
```

will be

```
window.open(href, windowname, 'width=400,height=200,scrollbars=yes', '_self' );
```

Also, refer to the link,

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_win_open

Answer (score 0):

You should try this..
Place the below code within your php file where you are redirected from gmail within your php page function

```
echo "<script>window.opener.location.reload();window.close();</script>";
```

or you can do it within your js file as

```
<script>
    window.onunload = RefreshParent;
    function RefreshParent() {
        if (window.opener != null && !window.opener.closed) {
            window.opener.location.reload();
        }
    }        
</script>
```

Comment: Its good that it works but just select mine or WisdmLabs answer so this might help others that you got your answer

Comment: If its mine just upvote or accept it as answer so next time the same question may be helpful to others

Comment: As you can't upvote as you don't have that privileges but you can accept it as answer